# nginx redirect all traffic

Tags: nginx

domain.com and b.domain.com. Both subdomains are on different servers. I'm using nginx as my webserver. What must I change to nginx.conf to redirect all traffic from a.domain.com to b.domain.com?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

pjmorse's answer is good (so I upvoted it), but I use a slightly different scheme on a.domain:

```
server {
  server_name a.domain.com c.domain.com d.domain.com;    # you can serve any number of redirects from here...
  listen 80;
  rewrite (.*) http://b.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

This returns a HTTP 301 return code (moved permanently) instead of the 307 that some webservers may return.

Answer (score 3):

This question could stand to provide more details. Can we assume nginx is the httpd on both servers? What kind of configuration is already in place?

[This howto](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) gives a hint which leads me to suggest this:

On server `a.domain.com`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  a.domain.com;
    rewrite   ^  http://b.domain.com$request_uri?;
}
```

On server `b.domain.com`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  b.domain.com;
    // Remaining vhost configuration
}
```

Comment: The documentation on the link suggests that this is wrong way to do it and offers a right one.

Comment: This answer is six years old, and it is entirely likely that the right way to do it has changed. Feel free to provide a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    server_name
        a.domain.com
    ;
    return 301 http://b.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

you could set up a permanent redirect from one domain to another.